# Manipulate Datetimeindex Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has DatetimeIndex. I would like to create an input, the user will write the date, then python will look up the first passed month.

Here's an example: df is the name of the dataframe

```
    date = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format:  ')        
    Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format: 2017-01-31
```

I would like that python will do df[date-1] and then print the result so that I get:

```
    2016-12-31    8.257478e+04
```

It's possible if the input date is in the index already, but I'm looking find a way when the input is not.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `value` in `index` and then `iloc` for selecting:

```
pos = df.index.get_loc(d)
print (df.iloc[[pos - 1]])
```

Sample:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2016-11-30')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10, freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
            a
2016-11-30  0
2016-12-31  1
2017-01-31  2
2017-02-28  3
2017-03-31  4
2017-04-30  5
2017-05-31  6
2017-06-30  7
2017-07-31  8
2017-08-31  9

d = '2017-01-31'

pos = df.index.get_loc(d)
print (df.iloc[[pos - 1]])
            a
2016-12-31  1
```

If `date` is not in `index` add `method='nearest'`:

```
d = '2017-01-20'
pos = df.index.get_loc(d, method='nearest')
print (df.iloc[[pos - 1]])
            a
2016-12-31  1
```

But if need more general solution you have to use some conditions like:

```
d = '2017-11-30'

pos = df.index.get_loc(d, method='nearest')
if pos == 0:
    print ('Value less or same as minimal date in DataTimeIndex')
else:
    print ('Value nearest less or same as date', df.index[pos])
    print ('Previous value', df.iloc[[pos - 1]])
```